# Make a method that creates an array with given parameters?

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

So I have several arrays that I create with large CSVs with some basic code - no issues there. But I want to be able to make a new array from a CSV with a method instead of just copying and pasting code. Here's basically what I want to do.

```
public static void makeArray(String name, String path, int rows, int columns){
    //get CSV from path and make array with that data
}
```

But here's what I currently have, and it doesn't work.

```
static String[][] makeArray(String name, String path, int rows, int columns) {

    name = new String[rows][columns];

    Scanner scanIn = null;
    int r = 0;
    String inputLine = "";

    try {
        System.out.println("Setting up " + name);

        scanIn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)));

        while (scanIn.hasNextLine()) {

            inputLine = scanIn.nextLine();

            String[] inArray = inputLine.split(",");

            for(int x = 0; x < inArray.length; x++) {

                name[r][x] = inArray[x];

            }

            r++;

        }

        return name;

    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);          
    }



}
```

I appreciate the help!!

Comment: In what way does it not work? What exactly is the problem you are having? What does your debugger tell you is happening?

Comment: Java is pass-by-value, so remove the `name` parameter and `return` the newly created array.

Comment: Basically, I can't just make an array that way. I just want to be able to type in the name, path, rows, and columns and have the array made, but it won't pass the name of the array through.

Comment: Andreas - how do you return the array? I'm confused as to what that means?

Comment: @CarsonP Change return type from `void` to `String[][]`, and add a `return name;` at the end.

Comment: @Andreas, I just updated the code in the OP, but it tells me in Eclipse "cannot convert String[][] to String"

Comment: @Andreas, also, if you can put this in an answer, I will give you the check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has the following issues:

- Java is pass-by-value, so remove the `name` parameter and return the newly created array instead.
- Don't ignore exceptions. If you don't want callers to have to process the `IOException`, catch it and send an unchecked exception.
- Use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure your `Reader` is closed correctly.
- Don't pre-declare variables. Declare them where used.

Applying fixes for the above issue, your code becomes:

```
static String[][] makeArray(String path, int rows, int columns) {
    String[][] name = new String[rows][columns];
    try (Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)))) {
        for (int r = 0; scanIn.hasNextLine(); r++) {
            String inputLine = scanIn.nextLine();
            String[] inArray = inputLine.split(",");
            for (int x = 0; x < inArray.length; x++) {
                name[r][x] = inArray[x];
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error reading file '" + path + "': " + e, e);
    }
    return name;
}
```

Be aware that the code will fail if the file contains too many lines, or if a line contains too many values. You might want to check for that, or make the code figure out the number of rows by itself, e.g. using a `List`.

---

**UPDATE**

To auto-create an array with the number of rows actually found in the file, you can use the following code.

The code also uses the [`Arrays.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) method to make sure every row is the given number of columns. If a line in the file contains more values than that, they are silently discarded.

```
static String[][] makeArray(String path, int columns) {
    List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path)))) {
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] values = in.nextLine().split(",");
            rows.add(Arrays.copyOf(values, columns)); // ignores excessive values
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error reading file '" + path + "': " + e, e);
    }
    return rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()][]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, how do I pass thru the name of the array. I obviously can't just have a bunch of arrays named 'name'

Comment: Also, give you give me a source that I can find to do the List thing to find out the rows for itself?

Comment: What do you mean by "name of the array"? Arrays don't have names. Variables have names.

Comment: @CarsonP You don't really need to pass any name for the array, you will just need to do that in the assignement: `String[][] names = makeArray("thepath", 5, 5);` and `String[][] ages = makeArray("thepathofages", 5, 5);`, then you just need to use the right names for your **variables**.

Comment: @Andreas, chsdk explained it, thank you both for all your help. How do I do the List thing you referenced for finding the number of rows?

Answer (score 1):

> Make a method that creates an array with given parameters?

The problem with your code is that you are not returning anything in your method due to `void` keyword and the fact that you didn't use `return` keyword.

So here's what you need to do:

1. First its return type should be `String[][]`.
2. Second you should return the edited array in the end of your method.

Another thing is that you are trying to assign a `String[]

```
name = new String[rows][columns];
```

Which will cause the Error `cannot convert String[][] to String`.

So in your method definition change the type of `name` to `String[][]  name` or even better declare it inside the method because you are initializing it in the method.

Comment: What should I do then?

Comment: @CarsonP in your method signature change the type of name to `String[][]`, take a look at my Edit.